# Sort Values in DataFrame using Categorical Key without groupby Split Apply Combine

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So... I have a Dataframe that looks like this, but much larger:

```
    DATE        ITEM    STORE   STOCK
0   2018-06-06     A    L001    4
1   2018-06-06     A    L002    0
2   2018-06-06     A    L003    4
3   2018-06-06     B    L001    1
4   2018-06-06     B    L002    2
```

You can reproduce the same `DataFrame` with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

lojas = ['L001', 'L002', 'L003']
itens = list("ABC")
dr = pd.date_range(start='2018-06-06', end='2018-06-12')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(it.product(dr, itens, lojas)), columns=['DATE', 'ITEM', 'STORE'])
df['STOCK'] = np.random.randint(0,5, size=len(df.ITEM))
```

I wanna calculate de STOCK difference between days in every pair ITEM-STORE and iterating over groups in a groupby object is easy using the function `.diff()` to get something like this:

```
    DATE       ITEM     STORE   STOCK   DELTA
0   2018-06-06    A     L001    4        NaN
9   2018-06-07    A     L001    0       -4.0
18  2018-06-08    A     L001    4        4.0
27  2018-06-09    A     L001    0       -4.0
36  2018-06-10    A     L001    3        3.0
45  2018-06-11    A     L001    2       -1.0
54  2018-06-12    A     L001    2        0.0
```

I´ve manage to do so by the following code:

```
gg = df.groupby([df.ITEM, df.STORE])
lg = []

for (name, group) in gg:
    aux = group.copy()
    aux.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    aux['DELTA'] = aux.STOCK.diff().fillna(value=0, inplace=Tr

    lg.append(aux)

df = pd.concat(lg)
```

But in a large DataFrame, it gets impracticable. Is there a faster more pythonic way to do this task?

Comment: Can you come up with a better [MCVE]? The input and output are different.

Comment: Both presented frames are the exact `.head()` of the code I´ve provided next

Comment: Next time it would be a good idea to seed your random generator.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to improve your groupby code, so this should be a lot faster.

```
v = df.groupby(['ITEM', 'STORE'], sort=False).STOCK.diff()
df['DELTA'] = np.where(np.isnan(v), 0, v)
```

Some  pointers/ideas here:

1. Don't iterate over groups
2. Don't pass series as the groupers if the series belong to the same DataFrame. Pass string labels instead.
3. `diff` can be vectorized
4. The last line is tantamount to a `fillna`, but `fillna` is slower than `np.where`
5. Specifying `sort=False` will prevent the output from being sorted by grouper keys, improving performance further

This can also be re-written as

```
df['DELTA'] = df.groupby(['ITEM', 'STORE'], sort=False).STOCK.diff().fillna(0)
```

Comment: First of all, thks for the input. It was very useful. Second: How would avoid iterating over gruoups if instead of diff(), you´re using ´rolling´ with a iterable window. Ex: The window value is contain  in one of the collumns?

Comment: @RodrigoTeixeira 1. no problem 2. you can't avoid iteration if you're using a custom function, sorry. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem. If you have any other followups, please open a new question.