# How to apply rolling function with iterable windows without using loops or iterating over (groupby) groups in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This question is actually an "spin-off" of this [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727342/sort-values-in-dataframe-using-categorical-key-without-groupby-split-apply-combi/)

But this time, imagine you have this ´DataFrame´ but much larger

```
      DATE  ITEM   STORE   LT  SALES
2018-06-06     A    L001    4      3
2018-06-06     A    L002    2      1
2018-06-06     A    L003    3      3
2018-06-06     B    L001    4      1
2018-06-06     B    L002    2      0
```

I added the column "LT" which stands for "Lead Time" and switched Stock for "Sales". This is just the head of the ´DataFrame´. You can reproduce the same with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

lojas = ['L001', 'L002', 'L003']
itens = list("ABC")
lead_times = {'L001':4,'L002':2,'L003':3}
dr = pd.date_range(start='2018-06-06', end='2018-06-12')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(it.product(dr, itens, lojas)), columns=['DATE', 'ITEM', 'STORE'])
df['LT'] = df.STORE.map(lead_times)
df['SALES'] = np.random.RandomState(seed=101).randint(0,5, size=len(df.ITEM))
```

If you read the thread, you see that the user @coldspeed provided the following answer to calculate the positional STOCK differences between days:

```
v = df.groupby(['ITEM', 'STORE'], sort=False).STOCK.diff()
df['DELTA'] = np.where(np.isnan(v), 0, v)
```

Now imagine that what we want now is to calculate the rollingsum (forward) of sales, in each STORE, but with the window parameter depending on the LT column. Producing the result  bellow (I´ll append the head and the tail together so you can see 2 examples):

```
      DATE  ITEM    STORE   LT  SALES   ACC_SALES
2018-06-06     A     L001    4      3         7.0
2018-06-07     A     L001    4      0        11.0
2018-06-08     A     L001    4      3        11.0
2018-06-09     A     L001    4      0         NaN
2018-06-10     A     L001    4      4         NaN
2018-06-11     A     L001    4      4         NaN
2018-06-12     A     L001    4      3         NaN
...
2018-06-06     C     L003    3      4         8.0
2018-06-07     C     L003    3      3         7.0
2018-06-08     C     L003    3      3         8.0
2018-06-09     C     L003    3      2         6.0
2018-06-10     C     L003    3      2         NaN
2018-06-11     C     L003    3      4         NaN
2018-06-12     C     L003    3      0         NaN
```

**[EDIT]**
There is the code I've used to compute the "**ACC_SALES**":

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['ITEM','STORE'])
auxlist = []

for (name, group) in grouped_df:
    aux = group.copy()
    aux.sort_values('DATE', inplace=True)
    aux.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    win = lead_times[aux.STORE.iloc[0]]
    aux['ACC_SALES'] = aux.SALES.rolling(window=win, min_periods=1).sum().shift(-1*win)
    auxlist.append(aux)

df = pd.concat(auxdf)
```

Is there a fast, vectorized "numpythonic" way to get this result without iterating over groups?

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how `ACC_SALES` is computed? If it's a rolling sum, why does it start at 7 when the only `SALES` observation in the first row is 3? Is the logic "for each `(DATE, ITEM, STORE)` tuple, add up all sales within the past `LT` days"?

Comment: The window rolls foward, starting by the next day. I´m going to edit the question e add the code